# discord.py - /level command place on leaderboard shows all registered members instead of the requested persons place

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Im making a leveling system. I want a user to know what place they are on the leaderboard with the /level command. I got it working, but once the command is executed, it spits an error saying `discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'level' raised an exception: InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before`. I've looked in the entire script to find whats happening and I couldn't find anything. I found out that tabbing the `await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)` would fix the error, but the place on the leaderboard is **completely** inaccurate. Removing the tab brings me back to the start with that error. Does anyone know how to fix this bug? Please and thank you.

edit: The error IS FIXED, I still need to find the problem why the placement is completely not accurate.

/level command:

```
@bot.tree.command(name='level', description='View your own level, or another members level.')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    try:
        if not member:
                # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
                with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    users = json.load(f)
                lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
                exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
                with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
                    data = json.load(file)
                data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
                sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
                current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
                current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
                next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3.2
                missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)
                messages_sent = int(exp // 4)
                for pos, (id) in enumerate(sorted_data):
                    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
                    embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
                    embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{messages_sent} Messages", inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Place on leaderboard", value=f"#{pos+1}")
                    embed.set_author(name=f"User: {ctx.user.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.user.avatar)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
                    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
        else:
            # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
            with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
            current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
            current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            messages_sent = int(exp // 4)
            next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3.2
            missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)

            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
            embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{messages_sent} Messages", inline=False)
            embed.set_author(name=f"User: {member.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested User ID: {member.id} | Sender ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
            if debug_mode == True:
                print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    today = date.today()
                    t = time.localtime()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")

            await ctx.response.send_message(embed = embed)
    except:
        embed = discord.Embed(title ="This user doesnt have a level :(",color = discord.Color.blurple())
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

**entire** leveling module code

```
message_cooldown = {}


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1.5:
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f'\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {message.author.name} has sent a message within cooldown, therefore, no xp')
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: Message sent too fast, not adding XP for user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
                return

        with open('level.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)
        if debug_mode == True:
            print(f"Debug: 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}. Server Name: {message.guild.name}")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    t = time.localtime()
                    today = date.today()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] 4 XP has been successfully added to user {message.author.name}.")


        # Update the last message time for the user
        message_cooldown[message.author.id] = time.time()

        with open('level.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/3.2))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f" Level up!", description="{} has leveled up to **Level {}!**".format(user.mention, lvl_end), color=discord.Colour.green())
      await channel.send(embed=embed)
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end
      if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {user.name} has leveled up to  Level {lvl_end}!")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                t = time.localtime()
                today = date.today()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {user.name} has leveled up to Level {lvl_end}!")

with open('level.json', 'r') as f:
    levelfind = f.read()

@bot.tree.command(name='level', description='View your own level, or another members level.')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    try:
        if not member:
                # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
                with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    users = json.load(f)
                lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
                exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
                with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
                    data = json.load(file)
                data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
                sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
                current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['experience']
                current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(ctx.user.id)]['level']
                next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3.2
                missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)
                messages_sent = int(exp // 4)
                for pos, (id) in enumerate(sorted_data):
                    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
                    embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
                    embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{messages_sent} Messages", inline=False)
                    embed.add_field(name="Place on leaderboard", value=f"#{pos+1}")
                    embed.set_author(name=f"User: {ctx.user.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.user.avatar)
                    embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
                    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
                if debug_mode == True:
                    print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
                if log_enabled == True:
                    with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                        t = time.localtime()
                        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                        today = date.today()
                        f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} checked their own level")
        else:
            # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
            with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
            current_exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
            current_lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
            messages_sent = int(exp // 4)
            next_exp = (current_lvl + 1) ** 3.2
            missing_exp = int(next_exp - current_exp)

            embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {} '.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
            embed.add_field(name="XP until Next Level", value=f"{missing_exp} XP")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar)
            embed.add_field(name="Total Messages Sent", value=f"{messages_sent} Messages", inline=False)
            embed.set_author(name=f"User: {member.name}\nServer: {ctx.guild.name}", url=ctx.user.avatar)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested User ID: {member.id} | Sender ID: {ctx.user.id} | Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}")
            if debug_mode == True:
                print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")
            if log_enabled == True:
                with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                    today = date.today()
                    t = time.localtime()
                    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                    f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed {member}'s level")

            await ctx.response.send_message(embed = embed)
    except:
        embed = discord.Embed(title ="This user doesnt have a level :(",color = discord.Color.blurple())
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)

@bot.tree.command(name="leaderboard", description="View the servers leaderboard. (Levels)")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Leaderboard for {ctx.guild.name}", color = discord.Color.blurple())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
            member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
            if member is None:
                embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - This user has left the server. :(", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
                if pos+1 > 9:
                    break  
                continue # This skips the current member
            else:
                embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
                embed.set_footer(text="Pro tip: Use /level [user] to view more specific information about that member")
                if pos+1 > 9:
                    break  
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    if debug_mode == True:
        print(f"Debug: {ctx.user.name} viewed {ctx.guild.name}'s leaderboard")
        if log_enabled == True:
            with open('botlog.log', 'a') as f:
                today = date.today()
                t = time.localtime()
                current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
                f.write(f"\n{today} {current_time} [INFO] {ctx.user.name} viewed a servers leaderboard")
```

JSON file example:

```
{
  "757383943116030074": {
    "123456789012345678": {
      "experience": 0,
      "level": 1
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 11/8/23:
I moved the `await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)` line back 1 tab, because I just found out that it just shows 1 and it doesn't work, now its showing the TOTAL amount of members registered onto the leveling database. The error **is fixed,** but I still need a fix for the leaderboard placement.

Comment: Still didn't fix the issue... I've tried basically everything, all they did was give me even more errors.

Comment: Could you provide which line exactly raised that error? Also „Hello“ again :D

Comment: ```await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)``` its at the /level command (self)  im trying to get the place on leaderboard to work but it just shows how many people are registered onto the database

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your code for a long long time I finally found your issue!

When you‘re iterating through the users in your list (`for pos, (id) in enumerate(sorted_data):`) you‘re iterating through **every single** user saved and create the embed every time with the user that called the command and the current position of the other users in `sorted_data`.

You have to check if the `id` is your users id in the for loop before creating the embed (`if id == ctx.user.id:`)

That was also the issue with the first problem you had, your code was trying to send an embed for every user in your saved data, but discord prevented that as you can only respond once to an interaction.

I hope you understood what I meant and if you got any further question don‘t be afraid of asking! ;D

Comment: It did **actually fix the error**, but now the message isn't showing up? I believe the message is not coming up on time, since I never got an error.

Comment: EDIT: i found the issue, it couldn't find the user, even though it exists